# How to monitor link'd modules with budo dev server?

Tags: reactjs, npm, browserify, npm-link, budo

my current front-end dev setup is below:

- browserify as build tool
- [budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) as a development server

I have a couple of shared modules packaged up and published on npm for use as a dependency among many projects.

However the development feedback cycle is too long since I have to run `npm link ../<repo> && npm run dev` every time I need to see an updated change and it takes too long to finish linking , approx. 2-5 minutes.

Is there a way I can watch changes in my link'd module and it will rebuild files that were changes?

Answer (score 0):

Budo (browserify) should follow symlinks, so once you `npm link` then you should be able to edit both modules concurrently (and get live reload) without having to re-run any commands. This is assuming your other module doesn't need a transpile step. If it isn't working, perhaps it's a bug or some other issue. Feel free to open an issue on budo's GH issues to discuss further.

– @mattdesl